# Server for a Chat Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-chrome-extension, server

I am trying to make a Chrome extension that allows a user to input a sentence and everyone else who has the Chrome extension will get it printed into their console. Obviously, this is more just a proof of concept for a bigger project but this is the bare bones. **How do I achieve this?** I can think of a couple of different methods like perhaps Amazon Web Services but I don't have enough experience to know if this is the right tool for the job. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try with Firebase. There is an example [here](https://www.cometchat.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chat-app-with-firebase) and another one [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-a-real-time-chat-app-with-reactjs-and-firebase/).

Comment: After a lot of testing, it seems that Firebase realtime database isn't really compatible with manifest V3 anymore. I got an example to work with manifest V2. Any other ideas?